# HTML5 Live Video Canvas Shape

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, canvas

I'm trying to create a circular frame (or canvas) for live HTML5 Video. I'm able to curve the corners with the keyframes radius property, but this leaves me with an oval, not a circle.

Ideally, I would be able to use a div object (png image) as a mask for the video. That being said, the div object is just a circle, so I would be happy to use a circle to mask the video, too.

Here is my current code:

```
<style>
  video, canvas {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 25%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        -ms-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden; 
  }
</style>
<video id="video" width="600" height="450" preload autoplay loop muted controls></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

It would be preferable to get a circular mask for the video rather than change the aspect radio so that the video would be squished. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Style the containing div and the video element separately. Add a -webkit-mask-image
to the containing div.

> The -webkit-mask-image CSS property sets the mask image for an element. A mask image clips the visible portion of an element according to the mask image's transparency.

**CSS**

```
.canvas {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   border-radius: 300px;
   -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%);
}

video {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -125px;
   left: -125px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="canvas">
    <video id="video" preload autoplay loop muted controls></video>
</div>
```

See if it works :)